# Looping through WMS Layers on a map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layer, wms

I am drafting an application with Leaflet. Basically, I need to add several WMS layers and then cycle through them with a timed loop. This is the code (still a draft, I don't tested it) but I am missing a function for "`showLayer(i)`".

```
  var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18}),
          mymap = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(41.69906, 12.39258), zoom: 5, maxZoom:8});

    var optionsArray =['opt1', 'opt2', ...];
    var layer = new Array(myoptionsArray.length);

    for (i = 0; i < myoptionsArray.length; i++) {
        l = L.tileLayer.wms(url, {optionsArray[i]});
        layer.push = l
        l.addTo(mymap);
        }


    function myLoop(){
      ...count on i....
      showLayer(i);
      timerID = setTimeout(myLoop, 500);
    }

    myLoop();

    function showLayer(i){
        ?????
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in your code `layer` (confusing naming!) is an `Array` containing instances of `L.TileLayer`...

```
function showLayer(i){
    layer.forEach(function(l){ l.removeFrom(map); });
    layer[i].addTo(map);
}
```

Also, notice that the correct syntax would be `array.push(foo)` and not `array.push = foo`. Also note that creating an array with a initial length might make `push()` add *more elements at the end* instead of filling up the array.